# Inflate imagebutton on fragment

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

First of all, I want to ask something, to know if what I'm doing is correct or wrong. I'm developing an interfaze for a car media, wich is supposed to be over the android stock.

It won't have fisical buttons, so I've created a menu_layout wich consists on 2 borders, each on one side, with imagebuttos from where you can access to navigator, phone, tuner, etc...

Inside this layout, there is a FrameLayout where dinamically I'll add the layout corresponding to what I need (media, navigator, phone...)

The main layout so, is a FragmentActivity, and I set the other "activities" as fragments.

But is resulting that doing this, I'm loosing some functionallity in some framents, so...

Could I define this fragments as FragmentAcitivities? Or they must be Fragment to be able to set the dinamically on the container?

I ask this, because one fragment is the PhoneView. This fragment contais the definitions for custom Imagebuttons that act as the dialer. Also, this frament inflates a layout with the editext, imagebuttons, etc... all necesary to define a custom dialer.

But when executing, I get this:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Imagebutton` at this line:

`button1 = (ImageButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.one);`  when defining the first button of the dialer.

So, is this because the fragment can't inflate a layout with this kind of resources??

**UPDATE -- Code added**

**phone_view.xml**

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:baselineAligned="false">

    <!-- Layout for the dialer -->
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/Right_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"        
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dialpad_horizontal_margin"
    android:background="#000000" > 

    <!-- Text field above the keypad where the digits are displayed -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/digits_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="@integer/dialpad_layout_weight_digits"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dialpad_vertical_margin"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/dialpad_background" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/digits"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:textAppearance="@style/DialtactsDigitsTextAppearance"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:nextFocusRight="@+id/deleteButton"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/deleteButton"
            android:layout_width="56dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:state_enabled="false"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description_delete_button"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_dial_action_delete" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- The dialpad itself -->
    <include layout="@layout/dialpad" />

    <View
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="@dimen/dialpad_vertical_margin"
       android:background="#66000000"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/dialButtonContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="@integer/dialpad_layout_weight_additional_buttons"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/dialpad_background">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/dialButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:state_enabled="false"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_call"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description_dial_button"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_dial_action_call" />

</FrameLayout>        
</LinearLayout>
```

**Dialpad.xml**

```
<TableLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/dialpad"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0px"
android:layout_weight="@integer/dialpad_layout_weight_dialpad"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dialpad_vertical_margin"
android:paddingStart="5dip"
android:paddingEnd="5dip"
android:paddingBottom="10dip"
android:background="@drawable/dialpad_background"
android:layoutDirection="ltr">

<TableRow
     android:layout_height="0px"
     android:layout_weight="1" >
    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/one" 
        style="@style/DialpadButtonStyle"
        android:src="@drawable/dial_num_1_no_vm_wht"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_button_one" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/two" 
        style="@style/DialpadButtonStyle"
        android:src="@drawable/dial_num_2_wht"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_button_two" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/three" 
        style="@style/DialpadButtonStyle"
        android:src="@drawable/dial_num_3_wht"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_button_three" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
     android:layout_height="0px"
     android:layout_weight="1">
    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/four" 
        style="@style/DialpadButtonStyle"
        android:src="@drawable/dial_num_4_wht"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_button_four" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/five" 
        style="@style/DialpadButtonStyle"
        android:src="@drawable/dial_num_5_wht"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_button_five" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/six" 
        style="@style/DialpadButtonStyle"
        android:src="@drawable/dial_num_6_wht"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_button_six" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
     android:layout_height="0px"
     android:layout_weight="1">
    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/seven" 
        style="@style/DialpadButtonStyle"
        android:src="@drawable/dial_num_7_wht"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_button_seven" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/eight" 
        style="@style/DialpadButtonStyle"
        android:src="@drawable/dial_num_8_wht"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_button_eight" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/nine" 
        style="@style/DialpadButtonStyle"
        android:src="@drawable/dial_num_9_wht"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_button_nine" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
     android:layout_height="0px"
     android:layout_weight="1">
    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/star" 
        style="@style/DialpadButtonStyle"
        android:src="@drawable/dial_num_star_wht"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_button_star" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/zero" 
        style="@style/DialpadButtonStyle"
        android:src="@drawable/dial_num_0_no_plus_wht"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_button_zero" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/pound" 
        style="@style/DialpadButtonStyle"
        android:src="@drawable/dial_num_pound_wht"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_button_pound" />
</TableRow>
```

**PhoneView.java**

```
public class PhoneView extends Fragment{
...

    ImageButton dialBtn;
    ImageButton clearBtn;
    EditText numTxt;
    ImageButton button1;
    ImageButton button2;
    ...

    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mRoot = inflater.inflate(R.layout.phone_view, null);
    return mRoot;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
    ...

    button1 = (Imagebutton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.one);
    ...

    /**Button1*/
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Set1(v);
        }
    });
}

public void Set1 (View view) {
    numTxt.setText(numTxt.getText()+"1");
}
```

**UPDATE 2 -- New error on LogCat**

After modifying the .getActivity() to .getVew(), now I'm getting this on LogCat:

android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class

at this line: `mRoot = inflater.inflate(R.layout.phone_view, null); from the onCreateView()`

at almost at the end tells: `Caused by: android.content.res.ResourcesNotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x101030e a=2}`

```
at android.view.View.<init>
at android.widget.ImageView.<init>
at android.widget.ImageView.<init>
at android.widget.ImageView.<init>
```

Have to say that I've tried the same code using Button in the dialpad instead of ImageButton and it works. But I need Imagebuttons.

**UPDATE 3 --**

Probably is the style definition wich is making this happen, so here is it to see what can be wrong:

```
<style name="DialpadButtonStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
    <item name="android:background">?android:attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
    <item name="android:soundEffectsEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

Comment: is R.id.one an ImageButton? Also you are not inflating. Android had took care of it for you when you call setContentView. Also you are asking that object to your Activity, not to your Fragment

Comment: Yes, is an imagebutton. Thats the thing, I don't call setContectView. PhoneView is a fragment so I call the layout with onCreateView

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I told you, you are looking for the button in the activity hierarchy but it is belongs to the Fragment view hierarchy. Change

```
button1 = (Imagebutton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.one);
```

with

```
button1 = (Imagebutton) getView().findViewById(R.id.one);
```

Still I am not sure why you are getting a `ClassCastException` instead of a `NullPointerException`. Before you run it again, clean and rebuild your project

Comment: Chaged .getActivity() to getView(), but still not working. Updated the post showing new error.

Comment: After doing some test, is the style wich is generating this, I'm trying to see wich parameter causes it

Comment: Yes, before that I'll update the post with the style definition to see if wee cant find what is causing this

Comment: Done it, the android:background style seems not to be available for old versions

Answer (score 0):

You need to find component on what fragment is inflating, not on main activity.
Search on fragment's layout

```
button1 =(Imagebutton) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.one);
```

Comment: Chaged .getActivity() to mRoot, but still not working. Updated the post showing new error.

Comment: try deleting R file once.